# How to get the requested contenttype of a REST-Request?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

Using JAXB for implementing a REST-Webservice, we have several methods that are producing output.

The class that contains all of these methods is annotated with `@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })`. If a request goes the happy-path (no errors occur), we return the POJO's in our methods and JAXB dynamically marshalls these objects into `application/xml` or `application/json`, as the client requested it via `Accept: application/xxx;` in the request header.

My question is how to get the requested content type, because if an error occurs, we are throwing a `WebApplicationException` with a response which should contain a custom error message formatted into the requested content type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### *You could...*

Inject with `@HeaderParam("Accept")`

```
public Response doSomething(@HeaderParam("Accept") String accept) {
    // you may need to parse it as the value is not always as
    // simple as application/json
}
```

#### *You could...*

Inject [`HttpHeaders`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html), where you have a couple options

```
public Response doSomething(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    String accept = headers.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT);
    List<MediaType> acceptableType = headers.getAcceptableMediaTypes();
}
```